# SQL - columns to row without pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, pivot

I'm looking for an efficient way to convert rows to columns in SQL server. I heard that PIVOT is function for that. However my use case is a bit different.

Actual table:

```
   ----------------------------------------
   | Id |Category| Part1  |Part2  |Part3  |
   ----------------------------------------
   | 1  |A       |5       |0      |0      |
   | 1  |B       |0       |1      |3      |
   | 1  |C       |0       |0      |0      |
   | 1  |D       |0       |0      |0      |
   ----------------------------------------
```

The result Im looking for:

```
   ---------------------------------------------------------
   | Id |Category| xxx    |yyyyy  |zzzzz  |ffffff  |hhhhh  |
   ---------------------------------------------------------
   | 1  |A       |5       |B      |1      |B       |3      |
   ---------------------------------------------------------
```

Is that even possible to make? Also I was thinking about Subquery (https://www.dofactory.com/sql/subquery).

Give me directions where to start. Thanks

Comment: You wrote SQL Server in the question's text, but tagged MySQL. Which one actually is it?

Comment: can you explain the logic behind this? is it t-sql or Mysql ?

Comment: Logic is not sound, it seems to me at least

Comment: What do 'xxx', 'yyyyy', etc. mean?

Comment: Why did `fffff`  is `C` instead of `B`?

Comment: Have you confused the rows in the sample data? Maybe it should read `0` in `Part3` for `Category` `B` but `3` in `Part3` for `Category` `C`?

Comment: It is sql server. xxx and yy column means nothing. no names columns. or you can say columns with names of any text

Comment: @stickybit no , sample data are correct

Comment: OK, then why does `C` have a `3` next to it in the result?

Comment: @stickybit sorry, you right. my bad. I edited the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use `CASE WHEN` with `MAX`

```
SELECT ID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Part1 > 0 then Category end) 'Category',
       MAX(Part1) 'xxx',
       MAX(CASE WHEN Part2 > 0 then Category end) 'yyyyy',
       MAX(Part2) 'zzzzz',
       MAX(CASE WHEN Part3 > 0 then Category end) 'ffffff',
       MAX(Part3) 'hhhhh'
FROM T
GROUP BY ID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/796a6/7/0)**:

```
| ID | Category | xxx | yyyyy | zzzzz | ffffff | hhhhh |
|----|----------|-----|-------|-------|--------|-------|
|  1 |        A |   5 |     B |     1 |      B |     3 |
```

if you want to do SUM in `part` column. you can use `SUM` function to instead of `MAX`

```
SELECT ID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Part1 > 0 then Category end) 'Category',
       SUM(Part1) 'xxx',
       MAX(CASE WHEN Part2 > 0 then Category end) 'yyyyy',
       SUM(Part2) 'zzzzz',
       MAX(CASE WHEN Part3 > 0 then Category end) 'ffffff',
       SUM(Part3) 'hhhhh'
FROM T
GROUP BY ID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/796a6/7/0)**:

```
| ID | Category | xxx | yyyyy | zzzzz | ffffff | hhhhh |
|----|----------|-----|-------|-------|--------|-------|
|  1 |        A |   5 |     B |     1 |      B |     3 |
```

Comment: Yes thats is exactly what i needed. 10q

Answer (score 0):

Not efficient, but if I had to do this, I would self-merge (merge it with itself) using the Id field a number of times (with some remaining of columns) to get to your desired answer.

as I said before, it's not a pretty solution but should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try with CASE WHEN:

```
select id, case when category='A' then category end as category, max(Part1) as xxx,case when category='B' then category end as yyyyy,
max(part2) as zzzzz,
case when category='C' then category end as ffffff,
max(part3) as hhhhh
from tablename
group by case when category='A' then category end, case when category='B' then category end, case when category='C' then category end
```